# Email Template Design with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, email

I have to create a responsive email template design. I have been designing for a while, but never had a chance to create email templates.

Can I use Bootstrap to create email templates, just like I would using a normal web-page with containers, rows and columns?

If not, are there any specific tutorials, templates or considerations that I need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are creating an email template, you must need to use inline styles for styling the entire template. Go through the following links, these links will help you.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think this will help you http://altssolution.com/blog/build-responsive-email-template-scratch/

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using any 3rd party CSS framework as you will have to load the entire CSS file which is not supported by some of the Email Clients.

Rather you can use the table system in vanilla HTML along with the use of frameworks like SASS or LESS which will compile into CSS that you can add up in the DOM itself.